# Change default source when execute "rails new"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

When I use `rails new` to create a new project, the source in Gemfile is default to `https://rubygems.org`.

But I need to use another source, how can I set that source as default, so that I don't need to change `Gemfile` by hand later.

---

**@Update:**

I want to change source because the default source is blocked in my area (what a pity ...), when executing `rails new` it would stuck at `bundle install`, after a timeout it fails with tips.

If I can't use the default source, but I have another available source, what should I do to finish the creating of the project?

Here is what I did after fail:

- Change source in Gemfile.
- run `bundle install`

Is that done? Or I need additional steps?

Comment: Not possible. This is the Gemfile that gets copied to your app: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile

Comment: Its not possible. Run `rails new --help` to look for the available options for `rails new` command.

Comment: @sevenseacat I updated the question, could give some tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for project that use `bundler` & `Gemfile` is:

- `gem install bundler`
- `bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org https://gems.ruby-china.com`
  Add more mirrors, so that don't have to modify Gemfile's source, for each new project.
  The additional mirror will be used if the default one is too slow or can't connect.

**Tips:**

- If some package still stuck, then might need to:

  - Edit `Gemfile` by hand, with best source in you region.
    e.g: `source https://gems.ruby-china.com`
  - Then run `bundle install`.